# Django: ModelChoiceField as MultipleHiddenInput

Tags: django

I am trying to render a `ModelChoiceFiel` using the `MultipleHiddenInput` widget but the template does not generate any inputs at all.

Here is what I am trying:

```
class PresetSelectForm(forms.Form):
    presets = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Preset.objects.none(), widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, presets, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PresetSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['presets'].queryset = presets
```

And in the template I am using the following:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
```

The csrf token input is generated, but nothing is for `{{ form }}`.

What am I missing?

**Edit**: I am including the essential and relevant code I am using in my view. It's just a `FormView`, so the `form` object is automatically created.

```
class PresetSelectView(FormView):
    form_class = PresetSelectForm
```

The overriden methods are: `get_form_kwargs`,  `get_context_data`, `form_valid`, `form_invalid` and `dispatch`.

I guess it's worth mentioning that I am not using the `form` instance anywhere in these methods except in `form_valid`, where I am getting `form.cleaned_data['presets']` but not modifying `form` at all.

Here is the overriden `get_context_data` method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    context = super(PresetSelectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # now some lines retrieving models

    # then we attach some additional attributes to the instances of some of these models (these attributes will be used in the template)

    context.update({...})

    return context
```

Comment: First, explain why you would want to do this. What's the point of a multiple choice field you can't see or select?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because the user is not actually going to select choices using the select dropdown, but using another custom UI component. Under the hood, the actual choice would be selected in the dropdown with JS (that is why I need it, but hidden), so submitting the form works as expected.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you show your view though?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't think it's relevant at all, and it's not a simple template. What would you be looking to see?

Comment: I didn't ask for the template, I asked for the view. We need to see how you're instantiating your form, and how you're passing it to the template context.

Comment: @DanielRoseman right, my bad; post updated

Comment: You should also post your overridden `get_context_data` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, I just updated my post